# Do Miche bottom brackets require a special tool, or is this one damaged?

Tags: bottom-bracket, tools

I just bought a Miche Primato bottom bracket and tried installing it using Park's BBT-5 (the same tool I used to remove the previous bottom bracket, also Miche, but from 2008). The BBT-5 fit into the right hand side cup without a problem, but I had trouble fitting it into the left hand side. I noticed that one of the splines is different than the others. Is this normal, or is this part defective or damaged somehow?

The spline in question is right below "ITALY":

[image]

Thanks for any help, I'd like to be sure before I complain to the shop I bought it from.

Comment: Could be a manufacturing defect.  Take it back to the store and have them compare it with other bottom brackets from the same manufacturer.  I bought an English bottom bracket last year where the drive side cup was Italian sized, and was therefore too big to fit in.  Turns out they got a whole batch of bottom brackets with the same problem.  They were able to give me a properly sized bottom bracket once they found a box with that had a correctly sized one in it. I'm sure the shop wouldn't mind helping you out on this, as long as you are polite and try no to make it seem like it's their fault.

Comment: yeah, I was going to say that looks like a manufacturing defect to me

Comment: Certainly can't expect a shop to inspect every part they sell for defects, so I didn't mean to imply I'd be suggesting it's their fault... this was in a sealed box after all. Thanks for the comments!

Comment: Shop agreed that this part is defective, was happy to swap with another one. FWIW the guy there said he'd never seen another Miche bottom bracket with this issue.

Comment: @spacemanaki can you please add your last comment as an answer and mark it as such ?

Comment: I will say that you see this sort of thing on the splines of a rear cassette, eg.  But that's to assure that all the sprockets fit on with the same orientation, and there's no point (that I can see) in assuring a single orientation when using a wrench on a BB cup.

Answer (score 2):

The OP notes: *"Shop agreed that this part is defective, was happy to swap with another one. FWIW the guy there said he'd never seen another Miche bottom bracket with this issue. –  spacemanaki Mar 29 '14 at 21:56"*

I just tried a google image search to see what they look like because I'm not familiar with Miche. The pic isn't perfect, but does give an idea that the splines don't have a taper on them like yours. Glad you were able to sort it with your LBS.
[image]